# How to restore the default Ubuntu 20.04 boot screen logo?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, themes, plymouth

I installed the KDE desktop over the default Ubuntu 20.04. After that I'm not seeing the default Ubuntu logo with Dell logo which is the new 20.04 feature. Instead seeing the Kubuntu logo.

How can I restore it back to the default Ubuntu Boot screen?

I tried

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

I was able to choose the ubuntu in manual mode:

```
There are 6 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/kubuntu-logo/kubuntu-logo.plymouth                       150       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth                                       110       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/kubuntu-logo/kubuntu-logo.plymouth                       150       manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/spinner.plymouth                                 70        manual mode
  4            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-budgie-logo/ubuntu-budgie-logo-scale-2.plymouth   149       manual mode
  5            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-budgie-logo/ubuntu-budgie-logo.plymouth           150       manual mode
* 6            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth                         100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
5

update-alternatives: using /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-budgie-logo/ubuntu-budgie-logo.plymouth to provide /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth (default.plymouth) in manual mode
```

--
But this didn't help. How to make the ubuntu to the auto mode ?

Could someone help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changes are also should be written into initramfs with

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

and then reboot to check effect.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. spinner.plymouth is the one that is default and I was able to set it. But it's appearing without the DELL logo. I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add comment yet so posting this as an answer. `bgrt.plymouth` is the one to choose to display manufacturer logo.